# Jenkins parallel script in loop using wrong variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to build a dynamic group of steps to run in parallel. The following example is what I came up with (and found examples of at https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/how-to-properly-achieve-dynamic-parallel-action-with-a-declarative-pipeline). But I'm having trouble getting it to use the expected variables. The result always seems to be the variables from the last iteration of the loop.

In the following example the echo output is always `bdir2` for both tests:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        script {
          def tests = [:]
          def files

          files = ['adir1/adir2/adir3','bdir1/bdir2/bdir3']

          files.each { f ->
            rolePath = new File(f).getParentFile()
            roleName = rolePath.toString().split('/')[1]

            tests[roleName] = {
              echo roleName
            }
          }

          parallel tests
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm expecting one of the tests to output `adir2` and another to be `bdir2`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to move the test section a little higher, and it will be work

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        script {
          def tests = [:]
          def files

          files = ['adir1/adir2/adir3','bdir1/bdir2/bdir3']

          files.each { f ->
            tests[f] = {
             rolePath = new File(f).getParentFile()
             roleName = rolePath.toString().split('/')[1]
             echo roleName
            }
          }
          parallel tests
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. I want to use `roleName` for both the `tests` array key and and the test itself which means I need to specify it inside and outside of the block. Not very DRY but I can see how the evaluation works now.